# How to call validation on a button click event thats not a submit type but a button type and without a form?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, bootstrapvalidator

I have been trying to figure this out, I know validation can be fired within a form as long as the button is of type submit. But I have a few other tabs on the view and when I use submit, it causes a posback and goes back to the first tab. I don't want that to happen so I put my validation in a function and changed the button type to a button and removed the form tag and tried calling the validation function on the button click event and its not firing. Is this possible to do without using a form tag?

My code is this...

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnUpdateModerator").click(function () {
        ValidateIt();
    });
    ValidateIt();
});
function ValidateIt() {
    var validator = $("#Users").bootstrapValidator({
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: "glyphicon glyphicon-ok",
            invalid: "glyphicon glyphicon-remove",
            validating: "glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"
        },
        fields: {
            DealerUsername: {
                message: "Username is required",
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: "Please Provide Username"
                    }
                }
            },
            email: {
                message: "Email address is required",
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: "Please provide Email address"
                    },
                    emailAddress: {
                        message: "Email address was invalid"
                    }
                }
            },
            password: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: "Password is required"
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 6,
                        message: "Password must be at least 6 characters long"
                    },
                    different: {
                        field: "email",
                        message: "Email and Password cannot match"
                    }
                }
            },
            confirmPassword: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: "Confirm Password is required"
                    },
                    identical: {
                        field: "password",
                        message: "Password and Confirmation Password must match"
                    }
                }
            },
            department: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: "Department is Required"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: If you don't have a form element, then what element is referenced by `$("#Users")`?

Comment: @JohnS, yes. #Users is a Div

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you need to keep the form element, but set the button type to "button" instead of "submit". You can then manually validate the form using the bootstrap validator's "validate" method.

Assuming your form element has the `id` of "Users", you should be able to change your code to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnUpdateModerator").click(function () {
        $('#Users').bootstrapValidator('validate');
    });
    ValidateIt();
});
```

Note: The `ValidateIt()` function as you have it written does not validate the form, it sets up the validator on the form.

---

Note: I think the API documentation is located here: http://bv.doc.javake.cn/api/

---

Update after your comment about making an ajax call:

If you want to make an ajax call when the button is clicked, but only if the form is valid, I believe you would do the following:

```
    $("#btnUpdateModerator").click(function () {
        $('#Users').bootstrapValidator('validate');
        if ($('#Users').bootstrapValidator('isValid')) {
            // Make the ajax call here.
        }
    });
```

Another way to write this is:

```
    $("#btnUpdateModerator").click(function () {
        var validator = $('#Users').data('bootstrapValidator');
        validator.validate();
        if (validator.isValid()) {
            // Make the ajax call here.
        }
    });
```

Comment: This kind of raises another question, I'm going to use an ajax call to pass the data to a database, will it still get called whether the fields are validated or not?

Comment: Thanks for sticking through with me on this, it is much appreciated. The second one is the one I was able to get working.

Comment: Thanks, You saved my life.

Comment: HI, can't we submit a form

Comment: Validation is working fine but when click on submit, the submit button gets disabled and form is not submitting

Answer (score 1):

I believe bootstrap validator binds itself to a form's submit() method, so moving it into a function won't actually help you. You can intercept the form's submit method though, and not allow it to submit until you want it to.

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // <-- prevents the form from submitting
    // do stuff
    this.submit() // <-- send it through
});
```

Comment: This would still cause a postback though and if I am in a different tab then after the submit it would go back to the first tab